# Order doc markdown files

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

We are using docusauros as the new tool to write down our documentation.
Is there a way to order markdown files under the `docs` repository?
At the moment when creating markdown files under `docs` repository, it orders them alphabetically.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A common strategy is to alter your file names so they're ordered like you want, e.g.

- `01-introduction.md`
- `02-details.md`
- `03-conclusion.md`

Comment: yes but there is a downside when you want to change the order again you will need to rename the relevant files. I had this solution in mind but thought maybe there is something more built in the system for it.